# Can I convert an iphone app on android within a specific time?

Tags: android, iphone

I have made an application which is using simple navigation, IBactions and some animation. I want to also convert it onto android platform but I dont have any idea about it. So i want to ask that can I convert it into 20-25 days or not? B/c I dont have extra time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "convert" the app from iOS platform to Android platform (usually).  If this is an HTML5 app, then it's a different story, but for a native app, you're for a complete rewrite.

If you are familiar with the Android framework and java, then you may be able to achieve what you want in a month, if your app is quite simple, but keep in mind that quite a few things that are available in iOS are not there in Android, especially when it comes to animation.

As an example, I am reasonably proficient with both iPhone and Android development.  I had a medium-level complexity app on iPhone (about 15 or 16 UINavigationControllers with plain user interaction - no OpenGL, 3D graphics, etc.) and the same functionality Android app.  It took me about 2-3 weeks to add a required piece of functionality to the iPhone app.  I am now in the process of adding the same functionality into the Android app.  I'm 2 weeks into the development and, by my guesstimates, I have about another 2 weeks left to complete it.

The main stumbling blocks while porting this functionality to Android are (1) animation: I spent at least a week getting page transition animation to work properly - something that I got working on iPhone in about 10 minutes; and (2) layouts: on iPhone you always work with the same screen size and you position components using absolute coordinates.  On Android, you have to take into account the variety of screen sizes and densities available and you'd have to ensure that your layout works with them all.  In a way this made my work easier, as something that I get for free from `LinearLayout` in android took me a good 1 day to complete on iPhone.

Judge for yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Aleks G.